# How do I use malloc properly?

Tags: c

Let's assume that I have a char variable that is going to hold 1000 bytes.

```
char var[1000];
```

How would I use malloc to allocate that much memory for whatever is going to be in there?

I've tried reading up on malloc, but even K&R did not seem to have much info on it.

Comment: "K&R did not seem to have much info on it" - Looks like you've read a different book :)

Comment: have you considered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work) ?

Comment: I did not down vote this... but I am guessing the problem is that this seems like a relatively easily looked up question (not only [are there duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788655/when-to-use-malloc-for-char-pointers), but there are plenty of examples you can Google up).

Comment: I've downvoted because your statement that there's little info on malloc is plainly ridiculous.

Comment: Did a Google search this is the first thing to come up so please don't down vote useful information.

Answer (score 6):

There should be millions of pages explaining the use of `malloc`, I doubt you did much searching. But here is how you call it:

```
char *var = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
```

For other types, just change it:

```
int *int_var = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
```

**Edit** Remember that you have to free the allocated memory after use! Or you will have a memory leak.

```
free(var);
free(int_var);
```

Comment: var = malloc( sizeof *var * 1000 ) is typically preferred over malloc( sizeof( char ) * 1000 )

Comment: these comments prove the usefulness of the question.  there is obviously some disagreement about how most properly to do this.  for instance I've seen others comment that you should use the `sizeof` the variable being pointed to instead of repeating the type, like `char *var = malloc(sizeof(*var) * 1000);`

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use malloc for this variable, because it's already allocated, but you may achieve similar results by using

```
char *var = malloc(sizeof(char[1000]));
// do stuff
free(var);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/

```
char *pVar = malloc(1000);
.... use pVar ....
free(pVar);
// DONT use pVar anymore
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared your variable as `char var[1000];` you already have statically allocated that much memory. You don't need to call `malloc` for this.

If you want to use dynamic allocation and your variable is declared like this: `char *var;` you can allocate the memory as follows:

```
var = malloc(1000);
```

also don't forget to free your allocated memory when you're done with it:

```
free(var);
```

Comment: @dikidera if its not a pointer then it already has its space and no malloc is necessary.

Comment: @dikidera: if you want to dynamically allocate memory, then you must use a pointer to store its address. If you want your variable to be an array, then you don't use malloc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `char var[1000]` you do not need malloc this definition allocates `1000*sizeof(char)` for your `var` so you can do something like var[999] = 'x';