# C Method returning string to Python via ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Few years ago I had to create a python wrapper for a C library. My knowledge of C is very limited but I managed to create what was needed.
Suddenly one method started causing issues, my only guess is it has to do something with python update.

In any case, I had the following C code:

```
const char * myFunction()
{
    return "My String";
}

DLL_EXPORT const char*
test()
{
    return myFunction();
}
```

which in my Python wrapper was called using the following method:

```
def test(self):
        ret = self.lib.test()

        return c_char_p(ret).value
```

As stated before, this was working well, although I'm not really sure why given what I've recently discovered while trying to fix it.

Currently that I'm getting 'Seg Fault' from python when calling the method test().

Using this threads:

[ctypes return a string from c function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883853/ctypes-return-a-string-from-c-function)

[When to use malloc for char pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788655/when-to-use-malloc-for-char-pointers?rq=1)

I managed to fix my code which now looks like this, c:

```
const char * myFunction()
{
    return "My String";
}

DLL_EXPORT const char*
test()
{
    const char* st = myFunction();
    char *bar = _strdup(st);

    return bar;
}
```

The python code remains the same. As said before, my knowledge of C is very limited and hence few questions:

1. any idea why the old implementation was working and suddenly stopped? Was there some python update that could have had affected it?
2. why in my c test() function  do I have to do _strdup(st) and return bar instead of simply returning st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using 64-bit Python?  The return type of `self.lib.test` defaults to `c_int` which is 32-bit.  If pointers are 64-bit you are truncating the pointer. 
 You are probably just getting lucky in your code change that the `_strdup` is located below 4GB in memory.

If you declare:

```
self.lib.test.restype = c_char_p
```

then this should work:

```
def test(self):
    ret = self.lib.test()
    return ret.value
```

Comment: Yes I'm using x64 Python. The new piece of code I have now works. What do you mean by 'change that the _strdup is located below 4GB in memory' ?

Comment: @stugal you changed your C code, and didn't get the failure. But I think your pointer is getting truncated, it may work in your new case just because the pointer address happens to be allocated below 4Gb, an address that fits in 32 bits. That may not always be the case. The correct solution is to specify the return type as a pointer, and leave your C code as it was originally.  Plus, the strdup version has a memory leak.

Comment: I'm casting the returned type to pointer. Also, how does it have memory leak? I mean it would if i wouldn't free the memory which I do in another method (that's a different subject)

Comment: @ Stugal. Casting is too late. The return type is a 32-bit int so if a 64- bit  pointer is returned it is truncated to 32-bits before your cast. Set the return type correctly. For your original code you didn't need to free the pointer, which was my comment about the leak since a free wasn't mentioned.